# Applying bottom padding to navigation bar

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, windowinsets, jetpack-compose-accompanist

I'm using the `BottomNavigation` from Accompanist and I want to have it drawn behind the navigation bar. I get the navigation bar insets from `WindowInsets.navigationBars.getBottom` but this value is way too high and creates a large gap (see image). How can I get the correct content padding for the navigation bar?

This is the code

```
@Composable
fun NavigationBar(
    navController: NavHostController,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
) {
    val density = LocalDensity.current
    val bottomPadding = WindowInsets.navigationBars.getBottom(density).dp
    BottomNavigation(
        modifier = modifier,
        contentPadding = PaddingValues(bottom = bottomPadding),
    ) {
        // content omitted for brevity
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

you can do it like this as the documentation https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/layout/package-summary#(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier).navigationBarsPadding()

```
class SampleActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            Box(
                Modifier
                    .background(Color.Blue)
                    .statusBarsPadding()) {
                Box(
                    Modifier
                        .background(Color.Green)
                        .navigationBarsPadding()) {
                    // app content
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

There is a dedicated extension function to convert the insets into `PaddingValues` and this yields the correct result:

```
val paddingValues = WindowInsets.navigationBars.asPaddingValues()
BottomNavigation(
    modifier = modifier,
    contentPadding = paddingValues,
) {
}
```

Comment: This is not available in Compose 1.2

Answer (score -1):

Try to not use the `innerPadding` in the `Scaffold` content.