# Compose BottomNavigation padding

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, bottomnavigationview, jetpack-compose-navigation, windowinsets

Im trying to properly apply a bottom window inset on the BottomNavigation composable. I have an edge to edge scaffold it looks like that:
[image]

When using:

```
modifier.navigationBarsPadding()
```

On the bottom navigation im getting the following:
[image]

I'm trying to achieve the following:
[image]

```
         Scaffold(
            modifier = Modifier
                .background(brush = NanitColors.blueGradient),
            topBar = {
                topBar()
            },
            bottomBar = {
                if (shouldShowBottomBar) {
                    BottomNavigationBar(navController)
                }
            },
            scaffoldState = scaffoldState,
            drawerContent = {
                Drawer { route ->
                    scope.launch {
                        scaffoldState.drawerState.close()
                    }
                    navController.navigate(route.route) {
                        popUpTo(navController.graph.startDestinationId)
                        launchSingleTop = true
                    }
                    currentDestination = route
                }
            },
            drawerGesturesEnabled = scaffoldState.drawerState.isOpen,
        ) { innerPadding ->
            NavigationHost(navController = navController, modifier = Modifier.padding(innerPadding))
        }
    
     val topBar: @Composable () -> Unit = {
            MainToolbar(
                modifier = modifier.statusBarsPadding(),
                title = title ?: "",
                onMenuClicked = {
                    scope.launch {
                        scaffoldState.drawerState.open()
                    }
                }
            )
        }

 BottomNavigation(
        modifier = modifier.navigationBarsPadding()
    ) {
        items.forEach { item ->
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
                item = item,
                isSelected = selectedItem?.route == item.route,
                onSelectedChange = { onSelectedItemChange(item) }
            )
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you use bottomBar inside a Scaffold? It would be better if you provide the code

Comment: What if you set same color to system bottom bar?

Comment: Added the code.
@AbdullahJaved I want it to be transparent..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74103810/7874746

Comment: @Evgeni have you got any solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [accompanist systemuicontroller](https://google.github.io/accompanist/systemuicontroller/) to set color to navigation bar, use default color for other screens and add color just for the screen you need:

```
@Composable
fun AppTheme(
    systemBarColor: Color = MaterialTheme.colors.background,
    content: @Composable () -> Unit,
) {
   ...

    SideEffect {
        systemUiController.setNavigationBarColor(
            color = systemBarColor,
            darkIcons = useDarkIcons
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't want to color it, I want the BottomNavigation the take up the whole space.. The "desired result" screenshot actually uses this technique, but this harms another UI stuff, like drawer and bottom navigation ripple effect..

Comment: 1. If you are following material design, bottom navigation bar background and navigation drawer background colors are the same, so you can set surface color for them as well as navigation bar. 
2. About ripple effect, it is not expected to have ripple on navigation bar.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Material3 than you could use the BottomAppBar(). This component supports WindowInsets. So it will automatically respect the system navigation bar and draws the background behind it.

```
Scaffold(
    ...
    bottomBar = {
        if (shouldShowBottomBar) {
            BottomAppBar(
                // you could of course also use WindowInsets.navigationBars
                windowInsets = WindowInsets.safeDrawing.only(
                    WindowInsetsSides.Horizontal + WindowInsetsSides.Bottom
                )
            ) {
                ...
            }
        }
    },
    ...
)
```